# How to make function in java that starts other function at specific time

Tags: java, function, time

I need to use java (unfortunately i don't know this code well) function that will be able to start another function at specific time. For example i set time for 13 next day and function automatically starts another function. I will be very grateful if someone would help me.

Comment: See [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: so you'll leave open your programm for days ?

Comment: I think max 4 hours, it was example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule tasks, but for schedules that are set several days in the future, you first need to answer if your application will be running that long. If not, you should look at `cron` jobs the native scheduler specific to your OS.

Answer (score 1):

**`java.util.Timer#schedule`**

See javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date- for more details

another (preferred) option is to use

**`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService#schedule`**

Comment: `Timer` is inferior to `ScheduledExecutorService`. You should prefer the latter from Java 1.5 or later.